# With Flickering Heart Quest - Is the Succubus guilty?

Tags: the-witcher-2

While investigating the murders of several young men Geralt follows the trail to a succubus. Using Dandelion as a lure he finally finds her lair. The succubus though denies any involvement in the murders, she claims her ex-lover Ele'yas killed them out of jealousy.

I confronted Ele'yas, but he too denied being the murderer. It is now word against word, and I don't know who to believe. Is there any way to gather more evidence to find out who truly murdered the young men?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you buy the surgical tools from the plant vendor just outside Vergen's inner gate and take them with you when you examine the body in the crypts, you'll be able to extract a metal fragment from the corpse's arm.

It appears to be part of a sword, and Succubi don't kill people with swords. But without anything to compare to, Geralt doesn't have anyone to place the blame on. Take the metal shard to Iorveth, and show it to him when you accuse Ele'yas of murdering the young men. Iorveth will compare the metal shard Geralt found to one of Ele'yas' blades and find it a perfect match.

There's your evidence. Now go back and rescue Dandelion!

Comment: This game sounds more and more awesome each time I hear of it. I'm gonna have to play that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the journal of the mission:

"**Siding with Ele'yas**:
Geralt decided that the succubus – guilty or not – was too dangerous to leave alive. He proceeded to kill the beast. The case was thus closed, but the mystery was never fully unraveled.

**Siding with the succubus**:
Geralt decided to accuse Ele'yas. He presented what little evidence we had gathered to Iorveth. The Scoia'tael leader wanted to talk to his subordinate, but Ele'yas was far away by then – he had fled. Still uncertain of the elf's guilt, the witcher went to tell the succubus everything.
Geralt decided that Ele'yas – guilty or not – would sooner or later kill the succubus."

So, we can't have sure who is the real killer behind those people that have been murdered.